# cakePHP passing URLs as a param

Tags: url, cakephp-2.0

I have an ImportController with a function admin_getcontents.

```
function admin_getcontents($url = null)
{
    $contents = json_decode(file_get_contents(($url)),true);
    //some stuff
}
```

Through ajax I call /admin/import/getcontents/ with:

```
$.get('/admin/import/getcontents/'+ encodeURIComponent($('#urlcheck').val())  ,function(data) {
      $('#importtable').html(data);
      $('#busy-indicator').fadeOut('high');
});
```

so I call the page: /admin/import/getcontents/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Feclipse%2Fanarxeio%2Fexport%2Fcontents%2F

Apache gives me an 404 error. If I call /admin/import/getcontents/1 the page loads correctly. So I figured to pass a ? before the parameter like:

admin/import/getcontents/?http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Feclipse%2Fanarxeio%2Fexport%2Fcontents%2F

Now I don't get a 404 error but $url param in admin_getcontents() is empty. How can I achieve the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to triple url encode your url:

```
// javascript
$.get('/admin/import/getcontents/'+ encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent($('#urlcheck').val())))  ,function(data) {
  $('#importtable').html(data);
  $('#busy-indicator').fadeOut('high');
});
```

Then url decode it in your php before you use it:

```
// php
function admin_getcontents($url = null)
{
  $url = urldecode(urldecode($url));
  $contents = json_decode(file_get_contents(($url)),true);
  //some stuff
}
```

**EDIT** following comments:

You will need to set up your routing to pass the url parameter. Looking at your setup, it should looking something like:

```
Router::connect('/admin/import/getcontents/:url', array(
  'controller' => 'import', 
  'action'     => 'getcontents', 
  'admin'      => true), 
  array(
    'url'  => '(.*)', 
    'pass' => array('url')
  )
);
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. The problem is with cakePHP because as I can see $_REQUEST has the url in its array. But cakePHP doesn't recognize the function param.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed you had set up your routes correctly. I have tested it, and it does work. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Plus you said you were getting a 404? How can you see the request object if you're getting a 404?

Comment: I don't get a 404 error when I put a ? after /admin/import/getcontents/ `admin/import/getcontents/?http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Feclipse%2Fanarxeio%2Fexport%2Fcontents%2F` In your example with th ecustom routing how do I call my function?

Comment: With your ajax call and the extra encoding, as I answered: `'/admin/import/getcontents/'+ encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent($('#urlcheck').val())))`

Comment: it works thanks. but if I put my real url: http://localhost/eclipse/anarxeio/export/contents/2011-07-20.json I have a problem. because encodeURI doesn't encode "." so when I call /admin/import/getcontents/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Feclipse%2Fanarxeio%2Fexport%‌​2Fcontents%2F2011-07-20.json cake thinks .json is an extension to getcontents

Comment: @gong Well that a separate question... In Your JS, check to see if there is a json extension and removed/replace the dot, adding it back in PHP side.

Comment: I didn't have time to implement it. I will try. But I am searching for a way to tell cake not to use . for parsing extensions, but using another character that javascript encodeURI will encode it